# mysql_connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known using file values

Tags: php, mysql

As wrote on the title I have this issue.
I have the data that allows me to connect to my database stored in a file. After getting those infos I tried to establish a communication with the database but I receive the warning

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\jstool\connect.php on line 21

twice and the result of the connect is nothing even if the values are correct (a.k.a. if I tried the connect writing down the values it works). 
Here's the txt file:

```
localhost
root
pwd
```

Here's the code:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$handle = fopen("config.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
   $i=0;
   while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $ln[$i]= $line;
        $i++;
   }
}

define("SERVER", $ln[0]);
define("USER", $ln[1]);
define("PASSWORD", $ln[2]);
$db = mysql_connect(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD);

if (!$db) {
    [...]
}
else {
    [.. reach database ..]
}
```

if i simply write

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pwd");
```

which as you can see are the values contained in the txt file, it works fine.

Comment: echo the value of SERVER before you connect to the database

Comment: done it. I've tried `echo SERVER." ".USER." ".PWD."!";` and the result was fine: `localhost root pwd!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [trim()](https://www.php.net/trim)

```
define("SERVER", trim($ln[0]));
define("USER", trim($ln[1]));
define("PASSWORD", trim($ln[2]));
```

from [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) manual

> Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (which
> is included in the return value)

so your read includes the newlines.

Comment: ok very well. Since the echo was not printing the new line I was sure that this couldn't be the problem. I was wrong! Thank you very much Ian!